# how to determine whether an idea should be treated as table or attribute in relational database?

Tags: database, relational-database, entity-relationship, erd

I'm a database beginner and i'm confused with regards to entity relationship. I don't know when should idea be classified as an attribute (i.e. a field) or as a table (i.e. an entity). Can you please help me understand this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terminology issues can be confusing.  And it's especially hard to help you because the experts and authors have not always been consistent with each other since the relational model was launched in 1970.  Here's how I learned it.

At the conceptual level, one is concerned with how values stored and managed by the database relate to the subject matter.  The subject matter is analyzed into entities and relationships among entities  (ER model).  Attributes are features of entities or relationships that can be described by data values.  Database values are instances of attributes.

At the logical level, one is concerned with a relational model of the data.  Relations in the relational data model are very much like mathematical relations, so that relational math can be presumed to hold.  The attributes discovered at the conceptual level become (named) attributes of relations.  Relations are sets of tuples with common attributes.  Tuples are identified by keys and referenced elsewhere by foreign keys.  Constraints on the data enforce certain business rules.  Values are stored at the intersection of an attribute and a tuple.

At the physical level, one is concerned with tables made up of rows and columns.  In addition there are database objects such as indexes and tablespaces that may be DBMS specific.  A table is a representation of a relation, where the rows represent tuples and the columns represent attributes.  Values are stored at the intersection of a row and a column.

SQL Server documentation tends to use the terms record and field where I would use the terms row and column.

The conceptual level describes requirements without regard to implementation.
The logical level is specific to a relational implementation.
The physical level is specific to a particular DBMS product, like Oracle or SQL server.

In practice, I express the logical level in SQL terminology, such as tables, rows, and columns, but I try to keep it free from DBMS dependencies.

I'm afraid that this description is extremely condensed.  Competent authors can take a hundred pages of text to flesh out what I've just said.  But I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:

Entities are anything we describe, represented by values in the keys of tables.  Attributes are the descriptions, one-to-one relationships represented by pairs of values.  Relationships are any association between sets of values, attributes are a special kind of relationship.  Columns represent value sets.  Tables represent associated value sets, thus one or more relationships.  Keys represent entities.  Foreign key constraints represent subsets of value sets.

Long answer:

Peter Chen defined attributes as functions that map from an entity set or relationship set to a value set (or Cartesian product of value sets).  He also explained that entities exist in the mind and are represented by values in the database.  Thus, entities are the conceptual domains of functional dependencies, i.e. in a normalized database, entity sets are what we represent by keys.

Attributes aren't equal to fields, rather they're mappings, represented in a table by a (key, value) pair.  For example, a person's age is an attribute, physically represented by a person ID and number of years in the Age field.  The Age column itself is just the image (dependent side) of the function.

It's clear from reading Chen's paper that entities aren't represented as rows in tables, contrary to common belief.  Entities are represented by values, attributes by pairs of values.  Thus, a relational entity table represents a relation, which may be one or more attributes, on an entity set represented by the key.  This also means we can have any number of tables describing the same entity set, allowing us to group related attributes together as needed.

For more, I would suggest reviewing basic set theory, e.g. [MathIsFun](http://www.mathsisfun.com/sets/), then reading Chen's paper: `The Entity-Relationship Model - Toward a Unified View of Data` (the PDF is available on the web).  The paper's bibliography references other useful papers.

Practically, it might help you to look at `Object-Role Modeling`.  ORM is an attribute-free diagram notation and discipline, and allows one to design a logical model without having to choose between entities and attributes.  That decision can be deferred to the physical design stage, and can be made according to the keys and functional dependencies in the model rather than arbitrarily.

Finally, Bill Kent explored conceptual issues in his book `Data and Reality`.  It's an excellent introduction to the topic of data modeling and relational concepts.

Comment: Very good point about the difference between entities and table rows according to Chen.  This is a very subtle point, and one that is commonly overlooked by people who treat ER modeling and relational modeling as different ways of doing the same thing.

Comment: It gets even worse, when people use an ER diagram to depict a relational model.